# display ajax response in modal/div - when the response is in form of webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am doing a ajax call - kind of ping operation to see if url provided by user is valid. It could be GET or POST request. I want to show the response of get/post request to user, so i am using a popup modal to display the response. But if the response is in form of a webpage, it is disturbing css styling for my original page (because of css styles in response webpage). **Is there any way so I can isolate this particular div separate from my webpage, so the styles are not disturbed**

following is code fragment for validating url provided in  `char`  variable (`ValidateURL` is rest API which validates the url and returns response and response code)

```
function validateURL(char){
    var value = char.value;
    $.ajax({
            url: "/FrugalPlatform/validateURL.action",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                url: value,
                protocol : protocol,
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#response").html(data.response);
                $("#modalForResponse").modal();
            }
    });
}
```

particular response returned was a webpage

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="//www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us" />
<link rel="shortcut icon"
href="//dnassets-mauganscorp.netdna-ssl.com/images/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml"
title="Desktop Nexus" href="//www.desktopnexus.com/opensearch.xml">
...
...
```

which contains number of resources linked...
which is messing up with my webpage styles...

[snapshot of one such scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtITd.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was directly trying to put the html response into a `div` element, which was disturbing the styles.. instead i m using `iframe` now, and modifying it's content dynamically as

```
var doc = document.getElementById('responseFrame').contentWindow.document;
doc.open();
doc.write(data.response);
doc.close();
```

where `responseFrame` is id of iframe